# Jdeveloper 12.1.2 installation (CMD property not found error)

Tags: jdeveloper

I was trying to install jdeveloper12.1.2  which i downloaded from oracle web site but when I was trying to install it  i got this error CMD property not found in autorun.inf.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Manetsus,I was trying to install jdeveloper 12.1.2 but every time i faced a issue with the message that CMD property not found in autorun.inf.  Earlier with Jdeveloper 11g it was quite easy installation process. I asked this question and answered it properly so that others can follow the steps for smooth installation.

Answer (score 0):

Installation of 12 c is not same as 11g . We are acquainted with the direct running of installer or .exe file in 11g but for 12 c the process is bit different. I search various answer but none of answer worked perfectly .

Here I will guide you with simple steps, just follow below steps patiently.

1. Download the installer file and unzip to a directory (Here I  have unzipped to D:\Software1).
2. After unzipped u will find a folder named Disk1.
3. Open your command prompt with **admin privilege**.
4. Go to folder Disk1 by using command  cd Software1\Disk1
5. Run the command C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin\java.exe -jar install/modules/ora-launcher.jar DISKCNT=1 JRE_COMPONENT=oracle.jdk,oracle.jre

**Give your JDK path** .. on previous command I have given mine.

6. Then follow wizard instructions for jdeveloper studio edition.

[I have attached image for the command prompt, Please follow it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cDCX.png)